# Using Graph API is it possible to filter items from a list/document library filtering by webUrl containing some text?

Tags: odata, microsoft-graph-api, graph-explorer

I'm able to get the items from a document library by querying the Graph like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{library-id}/items
```

And I get items back that look like the following:

[image]

Now I want to filter the results to get only items where the webUrl property contains the text '1808569'. So I change the query to:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{library-id}/items?$filter=contains(webUrl,'1808569')
```

And here is what I get back:

[image]

If filtering by webUrl not supported??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter list items only by fields. Filtering by any property (even by id) is not supported.

```
GET /v1.0/sites/{site_id}/lists/{list_id}/items?$expand=fields&$filter=fields/Title eq 'foo'
```

Not sure what exactly your value `1808569` represents in your case but as an alternative you can try to create a custom column on the list with this value `1808569` and then filter items by this custom field

```
GET /v1.0/sites/{site_id}/lists/{list_id}/items?$expand=fields&$filter=fields/CustomField eq '1808569'
```

Filter by field may require header `Prefer:HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly`

Comment: Yeah... already knew about the alternative.. not ideal, since the data to use for filtering is already there... is there any documentation and/or explanation from MS as why filtering on the list items properties is not supported?

PS: Given the limitation comes from Graph and the fact that because of it there can be no best answer to my question, I'll mark this one as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using filter = startswith(webUrl,'1808569')

Comment: I get a generalException back ("General exception while processing"). This URL used was .../items?$filter=startswith(webUrl,'1808569')